# How to block calls for selected numbers in android?

Tags: android

I am developing one application for managing incoming calls.

So the user can set any mode such as silent or call block for selected numbers.

Hi if it is possible,please provide source or reference links.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -2):

there is no way to block calls on android from java code. The only thing you can do is answer them and close.